# .deb Package for Stepstone (OpenNebula)

Tags: ubuntu, cloud, deb

I have installed OpenNebula on my cluster (Ubuntu 11.04) by using .deb packages provided by Ubuntu. But, it seems like that there is no web management system Sunstone.

Does anyone knows if there is .deb package for Stepstone? I realize that I could install Sunstone from OpenNebula's source, but I am not sure if it's possible without installing also  opennebula from source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenNebula Sunstone (not Stepstone) was released in OpenNebula 2.2, but Ubuntu still provides OpenNebula 2.0, the package hasn't yet been upgraded to OpenNebula 2.2, therefore Sunstone is not available with Ubuntu's package.

If you want to use Sunstone in Ubuntu 11.04 you need to compile from source. It's actually quite easy:

- Remove currently installed OpenNebula
- Create a oneadmin user: `sudo useradd -s /bin/bash -m -U oneadmin`
- [Download source code and unpack](http://downloads.dsa-research.org/opennebula)
- [Install dependencies required for compilation](http://opennebula.org/documentation%3arel2.2%3anotes#ubuntu_kubuntu)
- Compile: `scons`
- Install: `sudo ./install.sh -u oneadmin -g oneadmin`